# How can I prove that G is abelian?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$N$ is a finite normal subgroup of order $n$ of $G$, and $|\operatorname{Inn}(G)|=m$ , $(n,m)=1$ and $[G:N]=p$ a a prime number.
How can I prove that G is abelian?

Can I use that $G$ is abelian iff $\operatorname{Inn}(G)=\{ e \}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $(n,m)=1$, we know that $N$ is in the kernel $Z(G)$ of the epimorphism $G\to\operatorname{Inn}(G)$.
Then from the index we conclude that $|\operatorname{Inn}(G)|$ divides $p$.
Hence either $Z(G)=G$ (and $G$ is abelian) or $Z(G)$ is of coprime prime index in $G$. You may already know that this implies that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a little bit more about the first part: (n,m)=1 then N is Z(G)?

Comment: @IvanS.Guerra I only claim that $N$ is *contained* in $Z(G)$. For any $a\in N$, the inner automorphism $x\mapsto axa^{-1}$ has order dividing $|N|$ and order dividing $|\operatorname{Inn}(G)|$, hence dividing $(n,m)=1$. We conclude that  $x\mapsto axa^{-1}$ is the identity, i.e.,, $a\in N$ commutes with all $x\in G$.